Customize Jackson serialization/deserialization of child attribute from parent
I have a generic record that I use to send enum values with a description to my front-end:
public record EnumJson<E extends Enum<E>>(E value, String description) {
}

I have a single endpoint in which I provide many different enums in one response. It looks a bit like this (but more complex):
public record Enums(
  List<YesNo> yesNo, 
  List<RedBlue> redBlue, 
  List<UpDown> upDown, ...) {
}

For many of these enums, Jackson's default serialization mechanism of this E is fine (serialize using Enum.name()). However, for a handful of these enums, I'd like to customize serialization. I'm looking for some method to control the way E is serialized from Enums. Perhaps with an annotation like:
public record Enums(
  List<YesNo> yesNo, 
  List<RedBlue> redBlue, 
  List<@SomeInstructionToCustomizeSerialization UpDown> upDown, ...) {
}

I currently have a copy of EnumJson as follows:
public record SpecialEnumJson<E extends Enum<E>>(@JsonSerialize(...) E value, String description) {
}

However, it feels like there must be a better alternative.
Things that are not a solution in my case:

Add a custom @JsonValue to those handful of enums, because this would have an effect on how these enums are serialized throughout my entire application (which I do not want)


We're missing some key information. WHat are YesNo, RedBlue etc? How is EnumJson being used?

You are right, sorry about that! YesNo, RedBlue, etc. are enums. You can imagine them having values like YES/NO, RED/BLUE, etc. However, their values don't really matter in this question. What matters is how those values are serialized. In many cases, the default serialization is fine. However, I want to customize serialization of these values (deep inside EnumJson) from Enums. Is this possible (and how) is the question.

It's still unclear how EnumJson figures into this. How or where is it used?

If you need a custom serialization/deserialization logic only for some enum fields, then you could still employ the StdDeserializer and StdSerializer classes, customize the logic specifically for those fields, and finally add the @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize annotations before the interested attributes.
In your case, a customization for the List<UpDown> field in Enums could look like this:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Enums {
    List<YesNo> yesNo;
    List<RedBlue> redBlue;
    @JsonSerialize(using = SerializerListUpDown.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DeserializerListUpDown.class)
    List<UpDown> upDown;
}

public class SerializerListUpDown extends StdSerializer<List<UpDown>> {

    public SerializerListUpDown() {
        this(null);
    }

    public SerializerListUpDown(Class<List<UpDown>> l) {
        super(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<UpDown> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        int[] upDownValues = value.stream().mapToInt(UpDown::getId).toArray();
        gen.writeArray(upDownValues, 0, upDownValues.length);
    }
}

public class DeserializerListUpDown extends StdDeserializer<List<UpDown>> {

    public DeserializerListUpDown() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DeserializerListUpDown(Class<List<UpDown>> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UpDown> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode root = codec.readTree(p);
        List<UpDown> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < root.size(); i++) {
            for (UpDown e : UpDown.values()) {
                if (root.get(i).asInt() == e.getId()) {
                    list.add(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}

Demo
Here is also a demo at OneCompiler. As you can see from the output, the annotations manage to customize the serialization and deserialization for a List<UpDown> field by using the enum's value instead of its name.
Json => {"yesNo":["YES","NO","YES"],"redBlue":["BLUE","RED","RED"],"upDown":[2,2,8]}
Object => Enums{yesNo=[YES, NO, YES], redBlue=[BLUE, RED, RED], upDown=[DOWN, DOWN, UP]}


Thank you for taking the time to answer! Is it possible to generalize this custom deserializer if there quite a few of these exceptions (assuming we don't want to write/copy a serializer/deserializer for each of these exceptions)?

Each enum could be built differently, so I would say that you need to write a serializer and a deserializer for each one of them. If instead of enums they were classes, then you could have based the serializer/deserializer classes on a common base class.

I did manage to make it work (thank you @dani-vta!) but unfortunately the amount of boilerplate required is still unappetizing. I'm playing with the id to introduce a custom annotation processor that produces a Jackson mixin that I can use to get what I want, but that certainly sacrifices simplicity/transparency. I was hoping I could use standard Jackson features for this, but it seems like I can't.
